# Java How to select half part of string?

Tags: java, html, string

I have string like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and In java I want to after selection string looked like this:

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are dealing with HTML parsing then go for [JSoup](http://jsoup.org)

```
String html = "<html><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Elements fragment = doc.select("p"); // p tag
System.out.println(fragment.html());
```

- [Quick link](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: A little over kill don't you think?

Comment: _If you are dealing with HTML parsing_ I think OP just gave the basic example

Comment: Good point, I'm a fan of limiting the number of dependencies that a project needs. With out farther details, JSoup looks like a good library to use.

Comment: how to make array if i have tables ??

Comment: And why I can't split result string ??

Answer (score 0):

This one line should do it:

```
String text = input.replaceAll("(?s).*(<p>.*</p>).*", "$1");
```

Or to just get everything in the `<body>` tag, do this:

```
String text = input.replaceAll("(?s).*<body>(.*)</body>.*", "$1");
```

Comment: Then use this: `String text = input.replaceAll("(?s).*(<table>.*</table>).*", "$1");`. Also see edit

Comment: How to make array if i have two or more tables ?

Comment: This approach won't work for multiple occurrences. It's a simple string based approach that works for the simple case of one occurrence only.

Comment: why that code isnt working when html looks like this:
`<html>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>`
(when between is enter).
That code only works using that format:
`<html><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>`

Comment: The (?s) regex should make it work with embedded newlines. It works for me when o test it on http://www.regextester.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), it will be quit handy for you.